# Simple Method To Get a List of Items is failing after upgrade to EF 6

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

As the subject says we have some Repository and Unit of Work code on EF Core which is failing after upgrading the .net from 3.1 to 6.0 (and ef as well)

Exact code that is failing is below.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;
        foreach (var include in includes) query = query.Include(include);

        if (filter != null) query = query.Where(filter);

        if (orderBy != null) query = orderBy(query);

        return await query.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

I 've tried

```
return await query.SingleorDefault()
```

Does n't work.

```
return await query.FirstOrDefault()
```

Doesn't work as well.

In all cases I am getting the following error.

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EnumerableMethods' threw an exception.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element
   at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowMoreThanOneMatchException()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetSingle[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate, Boolean& found)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EnumerableMethods..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AllAnyToContainsRewritingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryTranslationPreprocessor.Process(Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MYProject.DatabaseLayer.Repository.BaseRepository`1.GetAsync(Expression`1 filter, Func`2 orderBy, Expression`1[] includes) in MyProject.DatabaseLayer\Repository\BaseRepository.cs:line 50
```

Comment: There's not enough info here to give you an answer. How are you calling this method?

Comment: Just a guess: `includes` contains duplicates.

Comment: No, it s not in all cases. You cannot get this exact error with firstOrDefault(). Or, you have another Single() in the méthodes passed as arguments (which is not a good practice, this exactly is the purpose of fluent API to avoid you to do this)

Comment: Something wrong with Library (.NET) versions. Exception is thrown because `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EnumerableMethods` static field initialization found two `Single` methods in `Enumerable` class.

Comment: I just posted an answer which will not fit as a comment and I hope to modify it when you have clarified. Is it possible to specify where you do the `return await query.SingleorDefault()` call. is it in a different method?

Answer (score 0):

I have quite a lot to say and it wont fit the comment so I hope I do not get marked down for this. And since as well there is not much context to know exactly what you are trying to do or achieve, I am going to try to assist as general as possible.

`SingleOrDefault` specifically does what it says. It looks for a single item so 1 or default which is 0. Which means if your query matches more than one result it will fail and send an exception.

`FirstOrDefault` on the other hand will then return the first result or none if none found.

I find it quite weird that it says `Sequence contains more than one matching element` and yet `FirstOrDefault` is giving same issue. You should check this again. I don't think `FirstOrDefault` gives such errors.

What I would advice is you simply print out everything in the query to a log or any how you want to do it and then check to see if what you are querying exists in the collection. as in check the existing data.

as well it will be nice to add to your question what you want to get since the fact that you used `SingleOrDefault` previously indicates you expected just one matching result.

Comment: If you analyze call stack, you will find that problem with static constructor execution.